# How to select the rows in R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I select the rows, which at least once have value 1 in all 4 columns? or have only 0 through all columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use  `filter` with `if_any/if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(if_any(everything(), ~ .== 1)|if_all(everything(), ~ . == 0))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df1[(rowSums(df1 == 1) > 0) | (rowSums(df1 == 0) == ncol(df1)),]
```